# Different eigenvector and eigenvalues in Eigen and Matlab could generate errors?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

Like it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860070/why-some-eigen-vector-signs-from-c-armadillo-are-different-from-python-and-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634638/c-linear-algebra-library-armadillo-how-to-use-eig-pair-to-get-the-same-resul) the orde of the eigenvalues (and relative eigenvectors and their sign too) are library dependent and (according to the first linked question) it shouldn't be a problem. In addition, eigenvectors relative to almost-zero eigenvalues can be considered as garbage. So far so good.

Now, consider the MATLAB code below that I want to rewrite in C++ using `Eigen` library:

```
%supposing K is 3x3 matrix
[V_K,D_K] = eig(K);
d_k = diag(D_K);
ind_k = find(d_k > 1e-8);
d_k(ind_k) = d_k(ind_k).^(-1/2);
K_half = V_K*diag(d_k)*V_K';
```

And my C++ implementation:

```
EigenSolver<Matrix3f> es (K,true);
auto v = es.eigenvalues();
//set to zero if eigenvalues too smal, otherwise v^(-1/2)
v = (v.array().real() > 1e-8).select(v.cwiseSqrt().cwiseInverse(), 0);
auto KHalf = es.eigenvectors()*v.asDiagonal()*es.eigenvectors().inverse();
```

The problem is that `K_half` values are different from `KHafl`, as you can see from the printed result:

Matlab:

```
V_K =

    0.5774    0.8428   -0.0415
    0.5774   -0.3806   -0.7468
    0.5774   -0.3806    0.6638


D_K =

   17.0000         0         0
         0    2.0000         0
         0         0   -0.0000

K_half =

    0.5831   -0.1460   -0.1460
   -0.1460    0.1833    0.1833
   -0.1460    0.1833    0.1833

eigenvalues=
 (2,0)
(17,0)
 (0,0)
eigenvectors=
(-0.842777,0)   (0.57735,0) (-0.041487,0)
 (0.380609,0)   (0.57735,0) (-0.746766,0)
 (0.380609,0)   (0.57735,0)  (0.663792,0)

KHalf=
(0.0754555,-3.9918e-310)  (0.0764066,1.9959e-310)  (0.0906734,1.9959e-310)
           (-0.144533,0)             (0.186401,0)             (0.200668,0)
           (-0.144533,0)             (0.186401,0)             (0.200668,0)
```

The problem is that I don't know if this difference is going to be a difference for the rest of algorithm or not (which I post at the end of the question for completeness). From what I understand there is no way to guarantee that the eigenvectors are the same from the two libraries (since there exists multiple eigenvectors and they are costant-invariant). Do I have to worry about this? Eventually, how can I solve it?

**The rest of the Matlab algorithm:**

```
% p and b int parameters , W and H returned
%create indices for the t random points for each hash bit
%then form weight matrix
for i = 1:b
    rp = randperm(p);
    I_s(i,:) = rp(1:t);
    e_s = zeros(p,1);
    e_s(I_s(i,:)) = 1;
    W(:,i) = sqrt((p-1)/t)*K_half*e_s;
end
H = (K*W)>0;
W = real(W);
```

Comment: Without really looking at the question, don't use `auto` with Eigen unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: I am hopping you mean `*es.eigenvectors().transpose();` or something like that. `v_K'` is the transpose, not the inverse

Comment: I guess your input matrix is symmetric. If so, then better use `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`, eigenvalues will be sorted and real.

Comment: @ggael no, its not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both answer's comments I figured out the problem:

```
Eigen::MatrixXcf KHalf = es.eigenvectors()*v.asDiagonal()*es.eigenvectors().transpose();
```

(using `transpose()` and `Eigen::MatrixXcf` made the trick)