# How to normalize a complex eigenvector/eigenvalue in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I know how to normalize a real eigenvector/eigenvalue (in general a real matrice):

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixXf> ges;

ges.compute(A);

VectorXf eigenvalues;

Eigen::MatrixXf eigvectors = ges.eigenvector().real();

for (int i = 0; i < eigvector.cols(); i++)
    eigvectors.col(i).normalize();
```

but what about complex eigenvector/eigenvalue?

Comment: eigenvectors computed by Eigen are already normalized. Note that they are still ambiguous by unit factors (i.e., if `v` is an eigenvector, then `-v` and `i*v` are eigenvectors as well)

Comment: @chtz thanks, but i don't understand this sentences: " Note that they are still ambiguous by unit factors " please give me more details.

Comment: Check e.g. Nicu's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634638